# Python magic is not recognizing the correct content

Tags: python

I have parsed the content of a file to a variable that looks like this;

> b'8,092436.csv,,20f85'

I would now like to find out what kind of filetype this data is coming from, with;

> print(magic.from_buffer(str(decoded, 'utf-8'), mime=True))

This prints;

> application/octet-stream

Anyone know how I would be able to get a result saying 'csv'?

Comment: IIUC, once the data is in a variable/string, why should any program be able to tell you the original format in which it was stored? At that point, that information is not present in the data itself. It would be better to get the metadata of the file itself when pulling the data out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `magic` on the original file.

You also need to take into account that CSV is really just a text file that uses particular characters to delimit the content. There is no explicit identifier that indicates that the file is a CSV file. Even then the CSV module needs to be configured to use the appropriate delimiters.

The delimiter specification of a CSV file is either defined by your program or needs to be configured (see importing into Excel as an example, you are presented with a number of options to configure the type of CSV to import).

Comment: Okay, I hoped I could read the content into a string and then still be able to predict the file format. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnDign That will work for certain file types a good example being media formats (eg images, audio, video etc) as they all have very specific file headers and or magic identifiers at the start that identify file type. Some text formats can be inferred eg XML, JSON, but CSV is probably the hardest to identify as the specification is so loose.